# How to retrieve data in monthly

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this kind of data

```
ID  Machine  State  FromDateTime       ToDateTime         DurDay
------------------------------------------------------------------
1   340      SB     1/7/2017 00:00:00  2/7/2017 09:58:03  1.4
2   340      PR     3/7/2017 01:23:55  30/9/2022 15:00:35 1915.57
```

I would like to display in monthly basis if the duration more than one month. Because I want to plot that month into value chart.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
 Select a.*, 
 Extract(YEAR from a.FromDateTime) || '-' ||
 to_char((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.FromDateTime)), 'FM00') as Ref_Month
 from mtable a

 union all

 Select a.*, 
 Extract(YEAR from a.ToDateTime) || '-' ||
 to_char((EXTRACT(MONTH FROM a.ToDateTime)), 'FM00') as Ref_Month
 from mtable a
```

And continue union minus 1-10 from the ToDate to get the monthly data. But this way only for Year-ToDate.

My expected output:

```
ID  Machine  State  FromDateTime       ToDateTime         DurDay   RefMonth  DurDay2
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   340      SB     1/7/2017 00:00:00  2/7/2017 09:58:03  1.4      07-2017  1.4
2   340      PR     3/7/2017 01:23:55  30/9/2022 15:00:35 1915.57 07-2017  27.94
.
.
N   340      PR     3/7/2017 01:23:55  30/9/2022 15:00:35 1915.57 08-2022  31
N   340      PR     3/7/2017 01:23:55  30/9/2022 15:00:35 1915.57 09-2022  29.63
```

Can anyone help on this query if I want to display all month and year in between this data?

Comment: Not very clear about what you try to achieve. Is Months_between what you are looking for?

Comment: @CjY, Yes correct. I want all month in between the dates.

Comment: Please provide an *expected* output for this sample data to clarify your requirement.

Comment: It's still hard to guess what the RefMonth and DurDay2 columns are. The first 6 input columns of last two records look identical. But RefMonth has different values for them, same for DurDay2 column.